# "fully stuffed with cash" or "stuffed full of cash."

Tags: verbs, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

While I was checking the meaning of **stuff** I found this two examples below.

> An old teapot stuffed full of cash.

and

> The wallet was stuffed full of pictures, letters, keepsakes and prayer
>   cards.

But I've learned that they should be *"stuffed with"*.

Could someone please analyze the two mentioned examples?

Comment: Where did you learn that it must be 'stuffed *with*'? It just isn't so.

Comment: @Jim Thank you :) By learn, I meant "I used to" use this kind of verbs(eg fill) with *"with"*. This structure is new to me. Is it common to say it in this way?

Comment: *Full* used in your examples is an adjective, not a verb if I understand your comment correctly. You can *fill with* "The box is filled with cash.", but *stuffed full* "The box is stuffed full of cash." is different.

Comment: @user3169 I know full is not a verb :) I am more curious about the sentence structure. What would differ if we say *"The wallet was fully stuffed with pictures, letters, keepsakes and prayer cards."* and why the original sentence is like that? Is it just a stylish way to say the same thing?

Comment: Maybe we can say, [[an old teapot stuffed with money] can be carried hardly]. Another way is that [an old teapot was stuffed with money]. or [I can stuff money into the case.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Stuff* is a complex-transitive verb.  It takes a direct object, but it *also* takes a PP complement (*stuffed **with** ...*) or an AdjP predicative complement (*stuffed **full** of ...*) with a resultative interpretation.

Compare *paint*, which can take a resultative AdjP:

> The house was painted **blue**.

Usually verbs that take complements of this kind take a fairly narrow range of AdjPs specific to that verb.  Some can take NPs as well.  In "the house was painted blue", *blue* is an adjective which describes the state of the house **resulting from** the act of painting:

> The house was painted **blue**.　　*(As a result, the house **is blue**.)*

Here are some more examples:

> She jerked the door **open**. 　　　*(As a result, the door **is open**.)*
>   He drained that sucker **dry**.   　    　 *(As a result, that sucker **is dry**.)*
>   She shot the bird **dead**. 　　　 　*(As a result, the bird **is dead**.)*
>   Kim knocked him **senseless**.　　*(As a result, he **is senseless**.)*

Each of these complex-transitive verbs takes an object (*door, that sucker, the bird, him*) as well as an AdjP predicative complement with a resultative interpretation.

Note that in each case, the AdjP isn't describing the way the action takes place.  *Dead* isn't the way she shot the bird; it's the state the bird is in after she shot it.  *Senseless* isn't the way Kim knocked him; it's the state he was in after she knocked him (senseless).

Now let's passivize the examples above and remove the actor from each:

> The door was jerked **open**.
>   That sucker was drained **dry**.
>   The bird was shot **dead**.
>   He was knocked **senseless**.

When you do this, the AdjP appears directly after the verb.  Your example is like this:

> an old teapot *(that was)* stuffed **full of cash**

By the way, this example taken as a whole is a noun phrase, not a complete sentence, so I didn't capitalize the first letter or put a period at the end.

> The wallet was stuffed **full of pictures, letters, keepsakes and prayer cards**.

This example is pretty much the same.  In either case, you could instead use a *with* PP, but it's not required.

Answer (score 3):

Their meanings are practically the same but they have different structures.

Let's compare:

- The wallet was stuffed **full of pictures, letters, keepsakes and prayer cards.**

  The verb *stuffed* is modified by the [adverbial phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase) *"full of pictures... prayer cards"*.
- The wallet was stuffed **with pictures, letters, keepsakes and prayer cards.**

  Here, the *"with pictures... prayer cards"* part is a [prepositional phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepositional_phrase#Prepositional_phrases).

Answer (score 1):

As Jim said, it's not **always** the case.

If you have seen *stuffed with* it **generally** refers to some dish where *stuffing/filling* happens.

Note that it's *stuffed with* and your sentences read *[stuffed] [full of]* which means the thing has many bills (cash), letters, pictures or things the like.

If it uses *with*, probably it goes like *stuff an old teapot **with** all the bills and coins you have.*

Comment: Thanks I understood your answer, but one thing is not clear. The first example. "The teapot stuffed cash" - the subject acts (In this case the subject stuffs). But how a teapot can carry on the action of stuffing on its own?

Comment: @Man_From_India it may be read like [An old teapot] [stuffed full of cash]. Maybe, as in *[An old man's brain] [filled with loads of ideas.]*

Comment: @Man_From_India Thank you, That is exactly what I am confused about.

Comment: @MaulikV In that case it's not a complete sentence, it's a part of sentence I guess...and other part of that sentence was omitted.

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks :) I believe we can also say : *An old man's brain stuffed with loads of ideas.* however, I am still confused :) What about the second example? would you please explain that a bit?

Comment: You may say that but I may not prefer calling *brain stuffed with*, instead, I'll make it simple using *filled*. This might make things clear - http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stuffed

Comment: Also, think about this: **X stuffed with...** and **...stuffed X with**. Hope this helps